# When changing a state, will only components that use that state render or do all components of the same level render?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Like my question react native or react is automatic calculate render when only state of component changed. Like example

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];
const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);



const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <Item title={item.title} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              setNumber(number+1)
            }}
            title={number.toString()}
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
          />
          <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

When set state number only button number rerender or all component include button in flatlist rerender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All component will be rerendered again if a change occurs in state of a component.

Comment: Yes, I belive that but my friend told me it not render because It will use shadown compare and only render component with state changed. So can you explain clearly?

Comment: A re-render can only be triggered if a component’s state has changed. The state can change from a props change, or from a direct setState change. The component gets the updated state and React decides if it should re-render the component. Unfortunately, by default React is incredibly simplistic and basically re-renders everything all the time.

Comment: So when set state the component re-render => all child will re-render?

Comment: The child will rerender only when props or states pass to the child component